# Method has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

My project is using MVC 4 C# LINQ to SQL.

For some reason the method used to get data for one of my properties is giving a "has no supported translation to SQL" error.  The method to fetch this data is nearly identical to the method of another property in the same query except the one that works grabs a string where the one that doesn't gets a decimal.

Exact error code:

```
Method 'System.Decimal GetModelDifficulty(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

I've tried numerous variations on the below code but I always get the same error as above:

```
public List<ProductionSchedule> GetBaseProductionSchedule(DateTime selectedDate)
    {
        var spaList = (from x in db.WO010032s
                       join y in db.MOP1042s on x.MANUFACTUREORDER_I equals y.MANUFACTUREORDER_I into x_y
                       where x.STRTDATE == selectedDate && (x.MANUFACTUREORDERST_I == 2 || x.MANUFACTUREORDERST_I == 3)

                       from y in x_y.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new ProductionSchedule()
                       {
                           MO = x.MANUFACTUREORDER_I,
                           BOMNAME = x.BOMNAME_I,
                           SpaModel = x.ITEMNMBR,
                           MoldType = GetMoldType(x.ITEMNMBR.Trim()),
                           SerialNumber = y.SERLNMBR,
                           Difficulty = GetModelDifficulty(x.ITEMNMBR.Trim())
                       }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Difficulty).ToList();

        return spaList;
    }

    public string GetMoldType(string model)
    {
        return db.SkuModelDatas.Where(x => x.Value == model).Select(x => x.MoldType).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public decimal GetModelDifficulty(string model)
    {
        return (decimal)db.SkuModelDatas.Where(x => x.Value == model).Select(x => x.Difficulty).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Strange - I believe both (`GetModelDifficulty` and `GetMoldType`) should give you the same error as method calls can't be translated to SQL...

Comment: Hmm odd I've used them before quite a few times I believe.  Also I've tested commenting out the GetModelDifficulty method and just setting it to 0 and the query then executes without issues even with the GetMoldType method left in there unchanged.

Comment: what is the type of `SkuMOdelData.Difficulty`?  why are you casting it to decimal?

Comment: type of SkuModelData.Difficulty is decimal? but the model object expects decimal so I have to cast it from it's nullable state.  I've also tried, inside the GetModelDifficulty method, to query the value then return 0M if null and the value if not but the extra logic didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Yes SkuModelDatas.Value is a system.string type in the dbml.

Comment: Have you tried **Decimal.TryParse Method** in your GetModelDifficulty() method. That might help you. Please check and comment.

Comment: ASP.NET is not relevant to your question, so I removed it from the tags.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  - if I'm not wrong `into x_y` should result into converting the remote query into local query. Once it becomes a local query it should be able to recognize the functions (GetMoldType,GetModelDifficulty) written in local C# code without any error. These two functions will not be passsed to remote data store as part of IQueryable query conversion. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've tweaked the code around enough times to where I've stumbled on a variation that works:

```
public List<ProductionSchedule> GetBaseProductionSchedule(DateTime selectedDate)
    {
        var spaList = (from x in db.WO010032s
                       join y in db.MOP1042s on x.MANUFACTUREORDER_I equals y.MANUFACTUREORDER_I into x_y
                       where x.STRTDATE == selectedDate && (x.MANUFACTUREORDERST_I == 2 || x.MANUFACTUREORDERST_I == 3)

                       from y in x_y.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new ProductionSchedule()
                       {
                           MO = x.MANUFACTUREORDER_I,
                           BOMNAME = x.BOMNAME_I,
                           SpaModel = x.ITEMNMBR,
                           MoldType = GetMoldType(x.ITEMNMBR.Trim()),
                           SerialNumber = y.SERLNMBR,
                           Difficulty = GetModelDifficulty(x.ITEMNMBR)
                       }).ToList();

        return spaList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Difficulty).ToList();
    }

    public string GetMoldType(string model)
    {
        return db.SkuModelDatas.Where(x => x.Value == model).Select(x => x.MoldType).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public decimal GetModelDifficulty(string model)
    {
        decimal difficulty = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model)) ? 0M : Convert.ToDecimal(db.SkuModelDatas.Where(x => x.Value == model.Trim()).Select(x => x.Difficulty).FirstOrDefault());
        return difficulty;
    }
```

Why it worked when trapping for null string for x.ITEMNMBR (model parameter) in one method and not the other and needing to OrderByDescending outside of the main LINQ query, I have no idea.

Thanks for all the suggestions and help with this.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your query is calling code that LINQ cannot translate into SQL.

First try this, it may help. There may be a problem with your `(decimal)` cast. Modify your method `GetModelDifficulty` to the following:

```
    public decimal GetModelDifficulty(string model)
    {
        return Convert.ToDecimal(db.SkuModelDatas.Where(x => x.Value == model).Select(x => x.Difficulty).FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

If that doesn't work I'm afraid you'll have to break your query down further to narrow down the issue. Use the documentation provided here: [Standard Query Operator Translation (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342%28VS.100%29.aspx) to be sure that any extension methods you are using have supported translations.

If you run into a piece of code that cannot be translated, you may need to declare a separate variable with the necessary value already stored inside of it, that you can then use inside of your query.

Comment: Good idea on trying the Convert rather than cast.  Unfortunately this seems yields the same error as before.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's because your call to FirstOrDefault() can return a null value. When you assign to a typed object you can use ? operator to signify that it can be null:

```
decimal? myDec = <some code returning decimal value or null>
```

Then you can check if myDec is null or not by:

```
myDec.HasValue
```

Comment: Not really, it's because it cannot be translated into a query.

Comment: I've tried trapping for the null value and having the method return 0M instead of null otherwise returning the value but it didn't seem to make a difference unfortunately.